# Xpath class id + text

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, import.io

I am trying to scrape permissions tables in the following site: https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfaDiAAJ

I am tryinng to find out if xpath is capable of locating a specific class with a text afterwards such as this (Please note ID are random so cannot locate using them, and also classes are the same for each table)

Advising on a home purchase plan

```
                    <div id="a2Nb000000035ohEAA" class="collapse DisciplineDetails PassportDetails PermDesc">
                      <h3 class="PermissionsListHeader">Advising on a home purchase plan</h3>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="PermissionConditionsList">
                      <li class="PermissionsConditionsItem">
                        Customer Type 

                        <ul class="PermCondsLimitationsList">
                          <li style="list-style: none"><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id110:regActTable:0:j_id531:0:j_id533:0:j_id535:0:j_id538"></span></li>

                          <li class="PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover">Customer</li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="PermissionConditionsList">
                      <li class="PermissionsConditionsItem">
                        Investment Type 

                        <ul class="PermCondsLimitationsList">
                          <li style="list-style: none"><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id110:regActTable:0:j_id531:1:j_id533:0:j_id535:0:j_id538"></span></li>

                          <li class="PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover">Home purchase plans</li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more on your requirement? Do you want to get the class name of the matching text or do you want to get the div of the matching text?

Comment: Hi Maheeka, and thank you for your help. Im trying to extract the table so that the XPath would find the table with the class "PermissionsListHeader" matching the text of "Advising on a home purchase plan" and would extract Customer Type (in this case "Customer" but there can be a few of these)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still, it is hard to understand what you want to achieve.. As far as I understand, you need to parse **PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover** class value(s) (in this case Customer) based on whether the **PermissionsListHeader** class attribute value equals "*Advising on a home purchase plan*". If so, then save value of **PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover** class attribute.

So the following logic should do the thing.

1. Parse the **< h3 >** and test the initial condition:

   //h3[@class='PermissionsListHeader']//text()
2. If the attribute value equals "Advising on a home purchase plan" parse **PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover** class.

   //li[@class='PermCondsLimitationsItem Popover']//text()

If the condition is not satisfied, just put the blank space etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the class of the element containing a particular text you can use the following xpath :

```
//h3[text()='Advising on a home purchase plan']/@class
```

If you need to get the whole div, use :

```
//div[text()='Advising on a home purchase plan']
```

Your requirement is not clear. If this is not what you are looking for , please explain more with the expected output.